# convert entire column with seconds to hours (pandas)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

there is such a dataframe

```
      x     laikas_s
0   meh         5237
1   elec       20925
```

I want to get such a dataframe

```
      x     laikas_s
0   meh      1:27:17
1   elec     5:48:45
```

in python i would translate it like this

```
import datetime

sec = 20925


a = datetime.timedelta(seconds=sec)

print(a)
```

how to do it in `Pandas`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pd.to_timedelta()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and specify the unit as second, as follows:

```
df['laikas_s'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['laikas_s'], unit='S')
```

Result:

```
print(df)

      x        laikas_s
0   meh 0 days 01:27:17
1  elec 0 days 05:48:45
```

Comment: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_timedelta'

Comment: @Вадим  Have you used `import pandas as pd` ?  Or you have other dataframe named as `pd` ?

Comment: Yes. 2 answer works, maybe this is due to the fact that there is a row in the column and not a second?

Comment: @Вадим  Pleased to help!  :-)

Answer (score 3):

I just add solution with `datetime.timedelta` (the result is string, without the `0 days`):

```py
import datetime

df["laikas_s"] = df["laikas_s"].apply(
    lambda sec: str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=sec))
)
```

Prints:

```
      x laikas_s
0   meh  1:27:17
1  elec  5:48:45
```